# Bracha on Listening to an online shiur

Tags: halacha, blessing

Does Having Torah classes run in the background or while multi-tasking count as limmud Torah where a bracha would be required to be recited if you are not totally focused on the shiur but catch various ideas intermittently?

Comment: Hi Yossi. Why would you suspect a blessing is not required here? You are learning Torah, even if you aren't learning so much. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I guess the question is whether that is considered learning - is that qualitatively considered learning which would allow the using of Hashems name - or is it having something run in the background  as opposed to listening to music for example.

Comment: Why would this not be considered learning since you are by definition of the word learning some things

Comment: @DoubleAA Or are you? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12299/is-listening-to-a-torah-tape-considered-talmud-torah

Comment: @ShmuelBrin If this question is asking if you can fulfill the mitzva of torah learning wihtout speaking, then that's a dupe.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was thinking of that

Comment: Normally, we say Birkas HaTorah at the beginning of the day and follow it with pesukim, mishnah etc. in order to fulfill the learning straight after the brocho. To answer your question, we would need to assume that the Birkas HaTorah was either omitted or its effectiveness was interrupted.

Comment: @DoubleAA, not sure what you need clarification of. The asker specified exactly why he thinks this may not count: "you are not totally focused on the shiur but catch various ideas intermittently".