# Doing Rambam using audio shiur?

Tags: torah-study, rambam, technology, chabad

Regarding the institution of the last Lubavitcher Rebbe to learn the Rambam, either 3 chapters a day or 1 chapter a day, does anyone know if one is [yotzei](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/608) by listening to and understanding a audio shiur of Rambam (and maybe repeating the Hebrew words) or does one have to read it from a book?

Comment: Are you asking if one listening to a shiur is *yotzei* the *mitzva* of *limud Torah* ?, if yes see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12299/is-listening-to-a-torah-tape-considered-talmud-torah) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/does-listening-to-torah-content-count-as-the-mitzvah-of-talmud-torah)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chabad provide two audio shiurim for one perek a day [here](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/rambam_cdo/jewish/1-Chapter-a-Day.htm#footnoteRef99a935201) which strongly suggests that they feel that it fulfills the requirements of the Rebbe zatzal.