# Words of Torah Need Not Be Enunciated

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, torah-study, rishonim, ritva

[Ritva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Tov_Asevilli) (commentary to Brachos 15b) writes that Torah need not be enunciated out loud during study.
Which other Rishonim espouse this view?

---

I am not asking regarding side issues such as verbal recitation facilitating memorization. I am only asking about the actual mitzva itself.

Comment: Are you asking about studying out loud versus silently, or are you asking about pronouncing the words properly versus incorrectly? If the latter, are you asking about Torah shebichsav or Torah sheba'al peh?

Comment: @Fred the former.

Comment: Got it. Are you asking this with respect to whether there is a requirement to recite *birkas haTorah* before silent study?

Comment: @Fred No. the parameter of Torah study to require a birchas Hatorah is not necessarily identical to the parameter of Torah study to fulfill ones mitzvah. Thus IIRC the Mechaber OH (57: 4) holds that one need not make a birchas Hatorah for silent study, yet it is a machlockes if he holds that one fulfills the mitzva.

Comment: The Shita M'kubetzes [takes this position](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%98%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%A1/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%91#.D7.93.D7.A3_.D7.98.D7.95_.D7.A2.D7.9E.D7.95.D7.93_.D7.91) (is the Shita M'kubetzes on B'rachos actually the Ritva, though?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encyclopedia Talmudis (הרהור כדבור) says that the Meiri holds this way (it does not mention the Ritva) and any Rishon who holds the Halacha is like Ravina that thought is equivalent to speech in regards to Shema would hold the same for words of Torah.

Comment: Where is the Meiri? What exactly is he quoted as saying?

Comment: @mevaqesh, you would have to check the Encyclopedia Talmudis. I saw it over Shabbos, I don't have it with me to check. My recollection is that he says it outright, no diyuk. But he might have been holding that הרהור כדבור.