# Can I make a siyum on audio lessons?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, torah-study, motzi-yedei-chovato, contemporary-halacha

I learned an entire Talmudic tractate by listening to audio lessons, without actually reading any words from the printed text. May I make a siyum?

It appears that "shomea k'oneh" wouldn't apply to audio recordings. Therefore, it's not clear whether or not listening to audio lessons would qualify as real Torah learning that one can make a siyum on.

Comment: _possibly_ a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1353/170

Comment: Have you seen how many audio recordings have been around for Daf Yomi? They've been there for years! Do you think all the participants at the latest Siyum last week who listened to audio made an invalid Siyum?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does listening to Torah content count as the mitzvah of Talmud Torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/does-listening-to-torah-content-count-as-the-mitzvah-of-talmud-torah)

Comment: Re duplicated, the rules of a siyum are different from the rules of *talmud Torah*. For instance, it might be talmud Torah to listen to a shiur on the parasha but you cannot make a siyum on it.

Comment: @DanF - yours is an excellent question!

Comment: @mbloch Can you elaborate on that? Are you talking about Shnayim Mikrah? Why would an audio on Torah differ from one in Mishna or Gemarah?

Comment: @DanF you don't make a siyum after learning a humash, or all five humashim, while you can make one on a seder of mishna or a masechet of gemara. However listening to a shiur on the parasha might qualify as learning Torah. As such the fact that listening to a shiur might qualify as learning Torah doesn't mean one can make a siyum on such shiurim. As such some of the duplicates proposed are in my view not real duplicates

Comment: This was seemingly how people did it for the first few thousand years of Jewish history

Comment: @DoubleAA that might be different if you need formal shomeah keoneh

Answer (score 3):

One can make a siyum even if the mesechet was learned without verbalizing it.

(ס’ יומא טבא לרבנן פרק ב’ אות ו’ בשם הרב אלישיב זצ”ל, וכן בס’ הדרן אלך אות ט”ו)

Also see ב”י סי’ תרס”ט בשם או”ז That the whole mekor to make a siyum is from a medrush that Sholmo learned in his dream.

איתא במדרש (שהש"ר א, ט): "א"ר יצחק, חלום היה עומד על כנו, חמור נוהק והוא יודע מה נוהק, צפור מצוצי והוא היה יודע מה מצוצי, מיד 'ויבא ירושלים ויעמוד לפני ארון ברית ה' ויעל עולות ויעש שלמים ויעש משתה לכל עבדיו' (מלכים שם), א"ר אלעזר מכאן שעושין סעודה לגמרה של תורה